# How to incorporate DATEDIFF() into hybrid_method?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a `hybrid_method` and I've got as far as:

```
@hybrid_method
def time_weight(self, date, daily_time_weight):
    days_diff = func.datediff(date, self.date_time_inferred)
    return min(daily_time_weight ** days_diff, daily_time_weight)
```

However, I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'float' and 'Function'
```

Because `func.datediff(date, self.date_time_inferred)` is returning a `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function` object.

Why is it doing this and how should I correct my `hybrid_method`?

---

**Update:**

Using the guide [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) I've now managed to get as far as:

```
@hybrid_method
def time_weight(self, date, daily_time_weight):
    delta = date - self.date_time_inferred
    days_diff = delta.days
    return daily_time_weight ** days_diff

@time_weight.expression
def time_weight(cls, date, daily_time_weight):
    days_diff = func.datediff(date, cls.date_time_inferred)
    return func.power(daily_time_weight, days_diff)
```

This works perfectly.

However, when I try to add the equivilent of `min()` as follows:

```
@hybrid_method
def time_weight(self, date, daily_time_weight):
    delta = date - self.date_time_inferred
    days_diff = delta.days
    if daily_time_weight ** days_diff < daily_time_weight:
        return daily_time_weight ** days_diff
    else:
        return daily_time_weight

@time_weight.expression
def time_weight(cls, date, daily_time_weight):
    days_diff = func.datediff(date, cls.date_time_inferred)
    if func.power(daily_time_weight, days_diff) < daily_time_weight:
        return func.power(daily_time_weight, days_diff)
    else:
        return daily_time_weight
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

On the line:

```
if func.power(daily_time_weight, days_diff) < daily_time_weight:
```

I'm getting closer but could do with getting over the line!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
@hybrid_method
def time_weight(self, date, daily_time_weight):
    delta = date - self.date_time_inferred
    days_diff = delta.days
    if daily_time_weight ** days_diff < daily_time_weight:
        return daily_time_weight
    else:
        return daily_time_weight ** days_diff

@time_weight.expression
def time_weight(cls, date, daily_time_weight):
    days_diff = func.datediff(date, cls.date_time_inferred)
    return case(
        [
            (
                func.power(daily_time_weight, days_diff) < 
                daily_time_weight, func.power(daily_time_weight, days_diff)
            )
        ],
        else_=daily_time_weight
    )
```

Key to this was working out how to use `hybrid_property.expression()` and making sure everything in it could be converted to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to invoke the MySQL `DATEDIFF()` function; you should be able to use Python's own date features:

```py
delta = date - self.date_time_inferred  # timedelta object
days_diff = delta.days
```

Comment: Thanks but a no go sadly... `AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'days'`. Worth mentioning that `self.date_time_inferred` is a `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>`

Comment: What are `type(date)` and `type(self.date_time_inferred)`?

Comment: Your comment and my edit to my last comment must have overlapped :) `type(date)` is `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`. I think the solution lies somewhere in here - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior but I can't figure it out

Comment: Gord - figured it out but you did really help my train of thought with the snippet above so I'll award the bounty tomorrow :)